# String operations in Visual Studio 2010 Reporting Services expression

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, expression

How do I take "16;#Name" and turn it into "Name"  (could also be "363;#DifferentName", etc)

I am trying to do this in an expression.

Right now...

```
RSet(Fields!Name.Value,InStr(Fields!Name.Value, "#"))
```

...seems to get me the exact opposite: "16;#"  But Trying LSet() or just different functions in general does not get me the answer either.

Comment: look at `String.Split`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=(Split(Fields!Name.Value,"#")).GetValue(1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly, I had tried Split() but neglected the ".GetValue(1)"

Comment: How about also checking whether or not Fields!Name has a name or not?  If there is no name supplied... it should return something like "No Name"    I found this: `Public Shared Function Test(s As String) As String 
      If String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) Then 
         Return "is null or empty" 
      Else 
         Return String.Format("(""{0}"") is neither null nor empty", s)
      End If 
   End Function`  But am not sure if there is a better way to do it without having to create more custom code. (I already have some in my report and I don't want to modify it if possible.)

Comment: You might be able to achieve similar result using inline `IIf` of `Switch` functions without resorting to custom code

Comment: Right, but I am not sure how to express this correctly with VB.  Like... IIF((Split(Fields!Name.Value,"#")).GetValue(1) Is Nothing, <true>, <false>)    ...I am guessing the "Is Nothing" is not the correct way to express the conditional for the IIF()

Comment: Will `Fields!Name.Value` will always have value and will it always end with #?

Comment: Ended up solving this with custom code:  `    Public Function SafeSplit(ByVal ToSplit As String) As String
        If Not ToSplit Is Nothing Then
            If ToSplit.Contains("#") Then
                ToSplit.Split("#")
                Return ToSplit.Split("#")(1)
            End If
        Else
            Return "Not Assigned"
        End If
    End Function
`

Comment: And the Expression looked like this: `IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Fields!Name.Value),"NoName",Code.SafeSplit(Fields!Name.Value))`